# Strange query results for DELETE with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In the following `DELETE` statement I try to delete all rows except the first one ordered by some criteria. (The actual query makes more sense, this is just a repro. All the `sys.objects` stuff is just for generating test data.)

Note the filter `r <> 1`. Yet, the `OUTPUT` clause outputs deleted rows with `r = 1`. How can this be?

```
USE tempdb
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT *
    INTO #o
    FROM sys.objects

    SELECT TOP 2 name FROM #o ORDER BY object_id --debug output

    DELETE k
    OUTPUT Deleted.name, Deleted.r
    FROM (
        SELECT k.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
        FROM #o k
    ) k
    WHERE r <> 1 --OUTPUT returns rows with (r = 1)

    SELECT TOP 2 name FROM #o ORDER BY object_id --debug output

ROLLBACK
```

Query results:

[image]

(The 3rd result set is complete - only one row.)

Note, that all rows except the first one were deleted. The numbering order of column `r` does not seem to match what was requested. And there is a row with `r = 1`.

This is SQL Server 2014 CU3 with trace flag 4199 enabled.

Comment: This is a one-off data migration script. I'm not personally interested in a workaround but it would be a useful addition to the question. It would be a useful answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [expected behaviour](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/682645/wrong-results-unhandled-exception-using-deleted-in-the-output-clause) at the moment

> the function gets evaluated on the DELETE stream.

So it actually behaves like this (pseudo code)

```
DELETE k
OUTPUT Deleted.name, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Deleted.object_id) as r
FROM (
    SELECT k.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
    FROM #o k
) k
WHERE r <> 1 --OUTPUT returns rows with (r = 1)
```

Although this is the currently defined expected behaviour it isn't really reasonable and they say

> Long term, we need to actually fix the behavior of OUTPUT clause to
>   match that of the ANSI SQL standard which will result in change of
>   results. So we will look at the correct semantics for a future version
>   of SQL Server since there might be apps that rely on the current
>   behavior.

I haven't tested on SQL Server 2014 but on 2012 the plan looks as the below.

[image]

After the delete operator (to the left) the column values from the deleted rows are sorted back into `object_id` order and the row_number re-applied.

It looks like the same is happening in your case from the results. (temp tables have a negative id and are sorted first before `sysrscols` which has a low positive `object_id` of `3`).

As well as the dubious semantics of the result the second sort by `object_id` doesn't seem strictly necessary in this plan as it looks likely that they will already be sorted in that order in any event.

Regarding workarounds for this specific case changing the output clause to `OUTPUT Deleted.name, 1 + Deleted.r AS r` would work.

For more complicated `WHERE` clauses I think you'd need a pass to calculate the row_number and then a join. e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE #o
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (object_id);

WITH k AS
(
 SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
FROM #o
)
MERGE k AS k1
using k AS k2
ON k1.object_id = k2.object_id
WHEN matched AND k2.r <> 1 THEN
  DELETE
OUTPUT Deleted.name,
       k2.r;
```

[image]

Results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need ROW_NUMBER and OUTPUT?  How about a nice set-based DELETE, eg something like this:

```
USE tempdb
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT *
    INTO #o
    FROM sys.objects

    -- Identify records to keep
    SELECT TOP 2 object_id
    INTO #keep 
    FROM #o 
    ORDER BY object_id

    -- Delete others
    DELETE o
    FROM #o o
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM #keep k
        WHERE o.object_id = k.object_id
        )

    RAISERROR( 'There have been no complex ANSI semantics issues during this set-based delete', 10, 1 )

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: How is this a workaround? Where are the row numbers of the deleted rows shown?

Comment: @ypercube It's a workaround for what I believed to be the general logic requrid for the query: "Delete some rows, keep these".  OP has also indicated it's a "valid workaround".

Comment: But you might as well suggest keeping the original code and removing the `output` clause as a "workaround" then. The only issue that needs working around is the unexpected result of that.

Comment: @martinsmith No I am suggesting set-based DELETE rather than DELETE with window function.  On reflection it's safer too.

Comment: There's nothing unsafe or un set based about deleting with a window function. Often it is the most efficient way. The semantics of the delete operation are fine here. The only issue is the unexpected re-application of the row numbering when computing the output result.

Comment: @MartinSmith By unsafe, I'm referring to the fact that when attempting to use this method and attempting to inspect the output using the OUTPUT clause, you run into an unexpected bug in the current SQL Server implementation.  Imagine if some logic was based on that output? eg Composable DML. That would then lead to a bug in app code.  Unsafe.  Regarding set-based, I am referring to the fact that my approach is a classic set-exception approach.  The original approach, assigning an artificial row identifier to every record in the set using window function extensions just to delete them, is not.

Comment: @wBob: This last comment seems reasonable. Yet, is your `TOP 2` set based according to your definition?

Comment: @ypercube Irrelevant.

Comment: Your approach uses `TOP` to identify which rows to keep. The OP's approach uses `ROW_NUMBER()`. It's anything but irrelevant.